# Linear space set problem

Tags: vector-spaces

Does $M_2=\{F(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]\mid \deg(F(x))<4;~F(80996)=0\}$ span a vector space.
I think it's false for multiplication, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What "is false"? And what does "for multiplication" mean for you? BTW, that set **is** a vector subspace of dimension $\;3\;$ in $\;M_2\;$

Comment: well af(x) does not equal f(ax) that what I mean, it's not closed under multiplication with a scalar.But if you can show me how to prove it that would be great.

Comment: Who says that's what scalar multiplication means, @user103220?? I think you're confusing things here badly: what you write is what a **linear map** must fulfill. We don't have linear maps here but polynomials!

Comment: So if F(80996)=0 then F(a*80996)=0, i don't get how that can be true.Please write the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

@User103220, by your comments I can see you're confusing things here: you **must** show $\;M_2\;$ is a subspace of $\;\Bbb R_4[x]\;$=all the real *polynomials* of degree less than $\;4\;$, and for this you need to show:

$$\forall\,f,g\in M_2\;\forall\,a,b\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;af(x)+bg(x)\in M_2$$

and this means that you must *prove* that

$$af(80996)+bg(80996)=0$$

But since $\;f(x)\in M_2\;$ then $\;f(80996)=0\;$ and...etc.